# How do I load image to a view?

Tags: ios, image, ios7

I'm very new to ios. I'm trying to load a image to my view. Here is my code:

```
-(void)loadView
{
    UIImageView *imageHolder = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 40, 40)];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];
    imageHolder.image = image;
    [imageHolder sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:imageHolder];
}
```

in my class named `Test` which is a sub class of `UIViewController`. `test.jpg` is in the same directory. When I run, I'm getting an error at this line:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];

Thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,address=0xbasd)
```

where I'm making mistake?

I'm using ios7 and xcode 5

Comment: May be error is else where your code is correct :)

Comment: check image extension may be its .png or .jpg. and check other image with same name may be issue in image also.

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem in your code. It cause infinity loop.
loadView - this method is called when the view is empty and you are responsible of creating setting view. 
When you access `self.view` your view is empty and loadView method will be called again, and it will finish in infinite loop.

```
UIImageView *imageHolder = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 40, 40)];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];
imageHolder.image = image;
[imageHolder sizeToFit];
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.view addSubview:imageHolder];
```

It's not important where image is located in you file structure. When you add a image to the project. 
You can do it by - drag and gripping image to the project. or by - "Add Files to Project"
When you add image you should select a target project you are adding it to.

Comment: `self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];` this line, where is the `frame` variable declared?

Comment: you can change it to - CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480),
or declare CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a loadView method, I think you should put your code inside `-(void)viewDidLoad` method. By the way, in Xcode5, you need to right-click on your project and "Add files to project" to add this image file.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImageView *imageHolder = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 40, 40)];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];
    imageHolder.image = image;
    [imageHolder sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:imageHolder];
}
```